# How to get numbers after comma in F#

Tags: f#

I want to get 4 numbers after comma in F# :
This is my code :

```
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.org
// See the 'F# Tutorial' project for more help.

open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let num = Console.ReadLine() |> float
    Console.WriteLine(num)

    Console.Read() |>ignore
    0
```

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: Example : 3.141567892 to 3.141 , I got 3 numbers after comma

Comment: so, you just want to round your float number, right?

Comment: [Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: SO it's awesome place to ask your question, but I think it's not always good for beginners with their many ans sometimes foggy questions.  So, I really advise you join to [F# Slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/). There is a #beginners channel, where you can get help with you question.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

And this's result :

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let num = Math.Round(Console.ReadLine() |> float, 3) 
    Console.WriteLine(num)

    Console.Read() |>ignore
    0
```